# Could someone explain the algorithm from this paper? (Thank you)

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, theory

Trying to get a fair understanding of our artificial immune systems. To do this I’ve been reviewing this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/6/1909), but the algorithm and mathematics is over my head, could someone explain the below to me in simple terms. Thank you

In the case of this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/6/1909), I’ve been able to understand that the system takes the IoT-Bot dataset. Then applies feature reduction through the use of the Information Gain algorithm so to remove features with a low ranking. And I understand the feature selection approach for this paper attempts to categorize signals as one of the following: safe, danger and PAMP.

But when it comes to how the below algorithm and mathematics actually work, I’m at a loss. Any help would be very appreciated.

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IKcy.png]

If you believe this question is inappropriately placed, please let me know where to post it and I'm happy to post it there instead. Or if this thread is missing details you believe are necessary, let me know and I'll add those.

Comment: I believe "explain this paper to me in simple terms" is too broad.    If you have a specific question about a specific aspect of the paper, that could be suitable here.   We are a question-and-answer site designed for focused technical questions about computer science.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: I encourage you to provide a reference that fulfills the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. This helps others with a similar question to find this page via search (e.g., via searching on the title of the paper).  Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142487/755, https://mathoverflow.net/q/397929/37212, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4202982/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49281/5038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68457708/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).